# failure to run mocha tests with sails

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, mocha.js

I'm following Sails docs and tried to run Mocha tests.
I've edited my `package.json` in the way the docs specified, but for some reason when I try to run Mocha I always get EACESS, permission denied error.

At first I got:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Library/Application Support/Apple/ParentalControls/Users'
```

I didn't understand why would it has to do anything with running my tests, but Added the required permission for this folder.

then I got:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Library/Application Support/ApplePushService'
```

Again, didn't understand, so changed the permission on this folder, which didn't help also.

I'm not understanding why would Mocha need permissions on these files , or how to fix it.

I ran the command :

```
mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js
```

And my project structure is exactly the same as in **Sails** tutorials.

I'm using **Mocha@2.2.5**. 
My co-worker cloned the repo, and tried to run the tests on his machine, but failed with exactly the same errors.

I tried downgrading to **Mocha@2.2.0** Which didn't help also.

The full error trace:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Library/Application Support/ApplePushService'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:761:18)
    at Glob._readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:609:20)
    at Glob._process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:393:15)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:427:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:426:9)
    at Glob._afterReaddir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:635:15)
    at Glob._readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:613:17)
    at Glob._process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:393:15)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:427:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:426:9)
    at Glob._afterReaddir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:635:15)
    at Glob._readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:613:17)
    at Glob._process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:393:15)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:427:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:426:9)
    at Glob._afterReaddir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:635:15)
    at Glob._readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:613:17)
    at Glob._process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:393:15)
    at Glob.iterator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:171:10)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at new Glob (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:169:22)
    at glob (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:57:11)
    at Function.globSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:76:10)
    at Object.lookupFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/utils.js:590:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:320:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:319:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: What does `ls test/unit/**/*.test.js` do? It seems like there might be a symlink to `/Library/Application Support/` somewhere in your `test/` directory.

Comment: Running the `ls` command returns : `test/unit/controllers/UserController.test.js test/unit/models/User.test.js` which are my two test files.  I didn't see any symlink there when searching.

Comment: maybe it's an issue with the specific directory your in? try running `npm cache clean` and then `npm install` again and run the command again and see if it works. If not, maybe try switching dirs?

Comment: Didn't help. Also tried to move the folder to a different directory which isn't a parent of the old directory - didn't help either.

Comment: Did you find your way ? This question is a bit old and i have the same problem.  mocha is scanning the whole disk and die on the first denied folder

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my [sails.js test example](https://github.com/albertosouza/sails-test-example). I think it may help you.

As in the code shown below, refer to [test/bootstrap.js](https://github.com/albertosouza/sails-test-example/blob/master/test/bootstrap.js).

```
var Sails = require('sails');
var _ = require('lodash')
global.DOMAIN = 'http://localhost';
global.PORT = 1420;
global.HOST = DOMAIN + ':' + PORT;
before(function(callback) {
  this.timeout(7000);

  var configs = {
    log: {
      level: 'info'
    },
    connections: {
      memory: {
        // lets use memory tests ...
        adapter   : 'sails-memory'
      }
    },
    models: {
      connection: 'memory'
    },
    port: PORT,
    environment: 'test',

    // @TODO needs suport to csrf token
    csrf: false,

    // we dont need this configs in API test
    hooks: {
      grunt: false,
      socket: false,
      pubsub: false
    }
  };

  Sails.load(configs, function(err, sails) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return callback(err);
    }

    console.log('rodo!')
    // here you can load fixtures, etc.
    callback(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  sails.lower(done);
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't help. Running the command 'mocha' by itself , regardless of Sails also return this permission denied error. I guess it has nothing to do with Sails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can help but I had a similar problem : as soon as i typed mocha in my shell, it were failing with a EACCES on a folder outside of my app. :

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:372
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/backup/mint17.3/etc/cups/ssl'
```

I found the bug came from file ./test/mocha.opt were i wrote a comment from sails.js docs :

```
/**
* @Doc :: This file should contain mocha configuration as described here:     https://mochajs.org/#mochaopts
*     
*    Note: The default test-case timeout in Mocha is 2 seconds. Increase
*      the timeout value in mocha.opts to make sure the sails lifting completes
*      before any of the test-cases can be started.
*/

--timeout 5s
```